# Is it wrong to use obsolete tags in HTML?

Tags: html, browser, standards, w3c, deprecated

What's so wrong about using obsoleted or not-yet-implemented HTML tags? Doesn't using them improve the portablity to older browsers? For example, today while validating some HTML docs I got this two messages:

> Warning: The language attribute on the script element is obsolete. You
>   can safely omit it.
>
> Warning: The bdi element is not supported by browsers yet.

I use

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

because in the case a user is using a very outdated browser (e.g. IE 5) that doesn't interpret the attribute **type**, it still works by interpreting the "obsolete" attribute **language**.

And

```
<bdi>
```

in the case a user is using a sufficiently updated browser which interprets it.

For all I know, if a browser doesn't "know" an attribute/element it just omits it so, is it okay to do this or I'm missing something?

Comment: You're targeting both HTML5-compliant browsers **and** IE5? A browser that was released over a decade ago? You're probably going to have to make the validator cry and simply ignore it. On the plus side, it sounds like you know your user base well, and that it's limited. Just ignore the validator.

Comment: Those messages are warnings and not errors, for exactly the reasons you describe. Usually they would indicate authoring errors, but are sometimes justified. You have a justification. It's fine.

Comment: Okay guys, I'll do that. I thought warning = against W3C standards but I guess I was wrong. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Well, using obsolete tags is okay as long as it is not necessary for the page to work. I would avoid using things like `<marquee>`, but I see no reason why your script element is wrong. Your bdi tag, however, if possible I would avoid, as not all browsers can use it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the W3C (draft) spec for HTML5, it's ok to use the language attribute on a  tag as long as it follows a couple rules, which yours appear to. The spec is calling this "Warnings for obsolete but conforming features". So I wouldn't worry about that one too much.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#warnings-for-obsolete-but-conforming-features

For other obsolete attributes, I've created a little bookmarklet that removes obsolete (in HTML5) attributes from a page so you can visually see what effect would take place if a browser ends up completely not supporting the attribute. Check it out here -> [attrebuke](http://keithwyland.github.com/attrebuke/)